# Who's standing behind Theoden in the "So it begins" meme?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

Who are the characters shown here, standing behind Theoden?

[image]

I don't know, and can't figure out who they are from the character list on [The Two Towers (film)](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Two_Towers_(film)) nor after a bunch of googling. This question is specifically for the above scene in Jackson's movie adaptation. Thanks so much.

*Edit*: This is of course during the battle at Helm's Deep. Thanks to any LotR buffs who might know. Someone sent this around at work and issued a challenge to name the three characters. All in good fun, and happy Friday!

*Update*: I rewatched TTT and took some video clips, it's a little easier to see the actors, see [this](https://youtu.be/1l29FvIQc0A), [this](https://youtu.be/9Vl8NUCc_74), and [this](https://youtu.be/vOxIXBpl4M4). Thanks @Valorum for figuring out the character on the right is Gamling, but the guy on the left is still a mystery! He has no speaking lines. [movie-dude](https://movie-dude.co.uk/[Extras]%20The%20Two%20Towers%20(2002).htm) refers to him as an unnamed extra (see #46). My wife and I went down the [list of actors, including those uncredited](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167261/fullcredits), and couldn't pick him out. The hunt continues!

*Update 2*: I got confirmation from a reliable source that the guy on the *right* in the picture is Gamling (actor Bruce Hopkins). It's much easier to tell if you watch [the video I linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOxIXBpl4M4&feature=youtu.be) (Theoden says "Give them a volley" and then you see a profile shot of Gamling shouting "Fire!"). Even though the guy on the left looks a lot like the picture of Gamling in @Valorum's answer, he is a different actor.

Comment: If (when) you win the prize for getting these names, I want half.

Comment: Haha you got it and thanks! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The chap on the right of the image is [**Gamling**](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gamling). The other guy appears to be an unnamed extra. Both are described in the script as "*Captains of Rohan*" and seem to serve as Theoden's loyal lieutenants throughout the battle, issuing orders on his behalf.

**Gamling**
[image]

Comment: I don't see the resemblance between the man on the left of Théoden in the picture in the Q and Háma. Besides, the relative heights look wrong, compared to the picture in your answer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Both characters are confirmed by name in the script/screenplay. Their heights seem right if you watch those scenes (there's at least two occasions where they directly interact with each other) and you have to take into account that in the scene above they're a) covered in rain and b) trying to look stern.

Comment: Apparently Jackson shockingly missed that the guy was called 'Gamling the Old', for a reason.  Might as well have made into one of the Helm's Deep elves.

Comment: @Valorum well, there you go!

Comment: "Gamling the Old" is actually a pleonasm of sort, since "Gamling" is an old Scandinavian word meaning "old man".

Comment: According to this: http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Hama  Hama dies in the warg attack in the movie. So this answer isn't correct.

Comment: Further research: the chap _on the right is Hama_, actor John Leigh. The chap _on the left is Gamling_ actor Bruce Hopkins. This answer does not answer the question and is also wrong.

Comment: @Amarth - For minor problems like people not knowing their left from their right, a simple edit would fix.

Comment: @Valorum The more serious problem would be that the people in the question bears no resemblance to those you linked. And that Hama is already dead (in the movie) before reaching Helm's Deep.

Comment: OP here, searching through [the screenplay](http://www.fempiror.com/otherscripts/LordoftheRings2-TTT.pdf) that Valorum linked to, Gamling seems correct, but Hama was previously killed by a Warg (p. 122). For the scene in question (p. 176), it says "ANGLE ON: THÉODEN stands ready *with his men*. LIGHTNING peels
across the sky accompanied by more THUNDER. THÉODEN looks up as
it begins to rain." May be time to rewatch, but it's possible the guy on the right is just an extra.

Comment: Update: I rewatched TTT on Saturday. It is much easier to tell in video (vs. still image) that the guy on our right is Gamling. Theoden says "Give them a volley" and then Gamling says "Fire!" (see [this](http://www.tk421.net/lotr/film/ttt/25.html) too). I will add some video clips. I still don't know who the character (or actor) is on the left, he has no speaking lines.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about Háma dying earlier. I knew something was wrong.